# Is there a particular configuration for WebStorm/SQLite

Tags: node.js, sqlite, webstorm

I start a project in Express/SQLite on WebStorm but my IDE don't find the sqlite3 Database class (sqlite3 library already install with NPM)

How can I configure the IDE to find sqlite3 Database class?

Code :

```js
const express = require("express")
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3")

const db = new sqlite3.Database("database.db")
```

`Database` is underlined in my IDE.

- WebStorm 2020.2
- Windows 10
- Node 12.18.3
- NPM 6.14.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing TypeScript stubs should help: put cursor on `sqlite3` in `const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3')`, hit `Alt+Enter` and choose **Install TypeScript definitions for better type information** to install typings - see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#ws_jsconfigure_libraries_ts_definition_files

[image]